# My Custom Module API Data not saving in magento 2

Tags: model, magento2-dev-beta, repository

I have created a custom module (Blog) which contains a `save()` method, it is executed but values are not saved and it returns an empty object.

```
<?php
namespace Learning\Blog\Model\Resource;
use Learning\Blog\Api\Data\BlogInterface;

class BlogRepository implements BlogRepositoryInterface
{

  protected $blogFactory;

public function __construct
    (
    \Learning\Blog\Model\BlogFactory $blogFactory
    ){
     $this->blogFactory = $blogFactory;
    }

public function save(BlogInterface $blog){

        $blog_Data = $this->blogFactory->create();
        $blog_Data->save();
        return $blog_Data;
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have achieved to update.

```
class BlogRepository implements BlogRepositoryInterface
{

  protected $blogFactory;

   protected $blogBuilder;

  protected $extensibleDataObjectConverter;

public function __construct
    (
    \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter $extensibleDataObjectConverter,
    \Learning\Blog\Model\BlogFactory $blogFactory
    ){
     $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter = $extensibleDataObjectConverter;
     $this->blogBuilder = $blogDataBuilder;
     $this->blogFactory = $blogFactory;
    }

public function save(BlogInterface $blog){

       $customerData = $this->extensibleDataObjectConverter->toNestedArray(
            $blog,
            [],
            '\Learning\Blog\Api\Data\BlogInterface'
        );

        $blog_Data = $this->blogFactory->create();
        $blog_Data->setData($customerData);
        $item = $blog_Data->save();
        return $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not able to do this I've got error : `Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Framework\\Api\\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter::toNestedArray() must implement interface Magento\\Framework\\Api\\ExtensibleDataInterface, instance of Vendor\\Module\\Model\\CustomModel given` Did you manage to get this working?